# Django postgres database not connecting with Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to connect `django.db.backends.postgresql` with my lumen application. But when I run the query then following error occured

> could not find driver

Even I change the driver type from mysql to pgsql

My database connection

```
'ml_db' => [
            'driver' => 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'host' => env('ML_DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('ML_DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('ML_DB_NAME'),
            'username' => env('ML_DB_USER'),
            'password' => env('ML_DB_PASS'),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_general_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'timezone' => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
            'strict' => false,
        ],
```

Is there any way to connect this database with my lumen application because I am using multiple databases in application.

Comment: You need install drivers for database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer here is, that you haven't installed the corresponding driver for your used dbms. So just install it.

Answer (score 2):

from your configuration posted in the question, I assume that it's your lumen configuration. There is no `'django.db.backends.postgresql'` driver in lumen. What we have is `pgsql` driver unless you create such a custom driver yourself,(which I assume is not the case).

so change the driver parameter to the following?

```
'driver' => 'pgsql',
```

Answer (score 0):

Lumen .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql  
DB_HOST=your host  
DB_PORT=5432  
DB_DATABASE=database  
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

[The link](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#configuration)